# Windows 7 Volume Deployment with OEM Licences

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

We have just ordered 80 Dell computers. We have chosen Windows 7 Professional on each of them (I assume this is an OEM licence).

Is it possible to deploy a customized image of Windows 7 Professional via lite-touch MDT, etc. on each of these machines without having to repurchase 80 more Windows 7 Professional licences (at ~$150 each) through Volume Licencing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lite-Touch MDT, but in a previous life, I'd build my base images from the included Dell OS restore CD, allowing me to use the S/N from the COA on the machine.  Is that an option?

Comment: Are you asking if this is technically possible, or if this is legally possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd919179.aspx) lists a Volume License media as a requirement for Lite-Touch deployment. You would need a Volume Key (or KMS) to activate these, so yes - it seems that Microsoft requires you to have a VLK, not OEM keys for this.

Can you skirt this requirement? Probably. Will you ever be able to get support from Microsoft if they find out? Not a chance.

You should talk to a licensing vendor, though. Many times there can be substantial discounts if you own OEM keys and just need VLKs of the same edition for deployment purposes. Obviously, YMMV.